# INSERT conflicted with FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep on getting an error saying:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Company__Locatio__239E4DCF". The conflict occurred in database "CIS11101Asset_HE"

Here is my code:

```
USE CIS11101Asset_HE
/*Add data to Company table*/
INSERT INTO Company
(Owner,Main_Branch,Manager,Agents,Admin_Assistants,Company_Name,Company_Phone,LocationID)
VALUES
('Jim Fassel',5542,'Jim Plunk', 'John Fish', 'Kerry Hyde', 'CakeCorp',313-455-1223,1),
('Jim Fassel',2254,'Jon Bourne','Choi Min', 'Paul Lee','StarCorp',313-663-1739,2),
('Jim Fassel',5542,'Jim Plunk','Jim Bean', 'Chris Rye','CakeCorp',313-457-1823,1),
('Jim Fassel',2254,'Jon Bourne','Joe Show', 'Paul Lee','StarCorp',313-663-1739,2),
('Jim Fassel',2254,'Jon Bourne','JC Bass', 'Paul Lee', 'StarCorp',313-633-1739,2),
('Jim Fassel',5542,'Jim Plunk', 'Abel Tee','Kerry Hyde','CakeCorp',313-455-1223,1),
('Jim Fassel',5542,'Jim Plunk', 'Pete Jo', 'Chris Rye','CakeCorp',313-457-1823,1),
('Jim Fassel',2254,'Jon Bourne','Kim Jog', 'Paul Lee','StarCorp',313-633-1739,2)
GO
```

Comment: your code is useless to us to figure out which value is giving that error. But the error message is really clear, there's a problem with a foreign key, go look at that and figure out the problem

Comment: you're trying to insert into table company which have foreign key to table Location. That last number in your values part is Location ID which refers to ID field in Location table. Because table Location does not contan row with ID 1 or 2, you're getting that error. Check table Location (or whatever it's name is).

Comment: The name of the foreign key suggests there's something wrong with the location. Verify your table with the locations having elements with ID 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be a bit surprised if the `company_phone` had something to do this this.

In the first row, you are inserting `313-455-1223`, which is -1365.  You see, this is a numeric expression, not a string.

I don't know if the phone numbers are stored anywhere else, but this could easily cause problems with check constraints, foreign key constraints, or triggers.

So, put single quotes around the phone numbers and see if that fixes your problem.